# Intentional combinational loops

Tags: chisel

I am designing some reconfigurable logic which, by its nature, could be configured to create a metastable combinational circuit.  Chisel compiles my circuit okay but stops me at the start of the run, having detected the potential of a combinational loop.

It is great and appropriate for Chisel to flag this as an error!  Since the combinational nature of the circuit is intentional, I now need to turn off the error so that I can proceed to testing the circuit's behavior on a range of valid configurations.  How can I do this?

Thanks in advance for your assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 2):

I found out from one of the comments in the bug database at gitHub that there is a command line option for this: --noCombLoop.  I will try this option and report back.  Thanks to dogngyukim for mentioning this on gitHub.

Comment: I tried this command line option, and it worked like a charm.